# Why jwplayer().seek() doesn't work for mp4 videos, mp4 videos are obtained by link to amazon s3

Tags: php, jquery, html, jscript

I am working on **jwplayer**, which can play both youtube and mp4 videos (mp4 : link from Amazon s3).
When a video is played and in between if we refresh the page, when the page returns the video should start playing from the position from where it was refreshed.
It works fine for me while playing youtube videos. But for mp4 videos, when the page is refreshed while the video has played, say 20 or 30 seconds its works fine, but it's not working when the player has played say about 40 seconds or more.

What's the issue?

I have tried:

```
this.seek(45); 
jwplayer().seek(45);
```

Answer (score 0):

jwplayer() needs an id as an argument. Try

```
jwplayer("yourPlayerDivId").seek(45)
```

Or

```
jwplayer = jwplayer("yourPlayerDivId");
jwplayer.seek(45);
```

seek official documentation : http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#seek